# How disable/enable scrolling in UITableView during one gesture (iOS - Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, isenabled

I need create similar detail view as in Maps app in iOS. This view is possible to pull out from bottom and contains UITableView. The problem is with enabling/disabling scrolling of table view. I know that table view has attribute *isScrollingEnabled*, but if I change it, it works only for new gesture. Is there any way, how could I enable or disable scrolling during one gesture?

Comment: Are you directly adding panGesture to tableView to make it draggable ?

Comment: @filip : u can try using `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf ` for more detail read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another

Comment: @iOSGeek I use container view sized over all screen, which contains panGestureRecognizer. Based on this recognizer is detail view draggable and this detail view contains standard UITableView.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I'd try it, but can you give me advice how to get reference of gesture recognizer of UITable view, if is it possible?

Comment: The problem isn't with conflict of more recognizers. The problem is with UITable view. I've tried created demo with only UITableView, where I've been changing _isScrollEnabled_ property repeatedly. It's able to stop scrolling, but if I set _isScrollEnabled_ back to _true_, the table view doesn't begin scrolling and it needs new pan gesture.